# Add wp posts to cutom masonry grid

Tags: php, posts, masonry

I need to create masonry grid containing the latest posts. I created a grid based on https://masonry.desandro.com/ - the grid displays correctly.

I am asking for help in creating a wp loop that will display posts in the grid.

This is my grid:

```
<!-- grid masonry layout -->
<div class="news-wrapper container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
    <div class="gutter-sizer"></div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"></div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"></div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"></div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"></div>
    <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

A single grid element should contain a single post (name of the post category, title, description, read more button). Posts should be displayed from the date of inclusion, from selected categories.

I created this code:

```
    <?php
    $args = array( array( 'category__and' => array( 55, 61, 53, 59, 57 ) ), 'post_status' => 'publish', 'orderby' => 'ASC' );
    $news_query = null;
    $news_query = new WP_Query( $args );
   ?>
    <!-- grid masonry layout -->
    <div class="news-wrapper container">
       <div class="grid">
                <?php if ($news_query->have_posts()) : ?>
                <?php $count = 0; ?>
                <?php while ($news_query->have_posts()) : $news_query->the_post(); ?>
                <?php $count++; ?>
       <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
       <div class="gutter-sizer"></div>
            <?php if ( $count == 1 ) : ?>
       <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2">
            <div class="card card-media">
            <a href="#">
              <div class="news-cat"><?php the_category(', '); ?></div>
            </a>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
              <p class="card-text"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
              <a href="#" class="btn"><span class="nav-text">Read more</span><i class="fa-xs fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
            <?php elseif ($count == 2) : ?>
          <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2"> (..and next grid item...)
```

I have introduced counting, because the grid elements have different styling (sometimes double width, double height), so I can not create identical grid elements in the loop, so how to change counting to display all posts (regardless of their number)?

Comment: The order of the different stylings is always the same (width2, height2, width2, width2, height2, height2) and repeats?

Comment: Yes, that was the idea of graphic designer...the next page of posts should be the duplication of the earlier, with the same arrangement.
Of course, if there are only 4 posts on the next page (instead of the next 12), boxes should be displayed and arranged according to the grid, but this is done by the masonry script.

Comment: Your code as written, will break pagination if you need such. The question as it is, is specifically about wrtting PHP code which is off topic here.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm wondering now, would it not be better to use a simple loop to display all posts from the category within the grid class div, each with the grid-item class, and then, for example, in JS add individual classes: ... width2 and. ..height2 to the right items

Comment: That would work if you added the classes before the masonry script runs. I would maybe look a little off while the page loads completely, but I think it would be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$count == 1` you should use `($count % 12) == 0`, 1, and so on till 11. This gives back the remaining of the division. So if `$count` is 6 you would get 6, but if `$count` was 16 it would give back 4.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned before, I created a single loop.

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
    <div class="gutter-sizer"></div>
        <!-- the loop -->
        <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>
        <div id="grid-item-nr-<?php echo $post_nr; ?>" <?php post_class( 'grid-item' ); ?>>
          <div class="card">
            <div class="news-cat"><?php the_category(', '); ?></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
                <p class="card-text">
                <?php if ( is_category() || is_archive() ) {
                echo excerpt(20);
                    } else {
                echo excerpt(20);
                    } ?>
                </p>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn"><span class="nav-text">Czytaj więcej</span><i class="fa-xs fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    <?php $post_nr++; endwhile; ?>
    <!-- end of the loop -->
</div>
```

Then I created a script (which I could certainly optimize ...) adding classes to the appropriate boxes, repeating every next 11 elements.

```
$(function() {
    var item = 0;
    var a = 0; // 1 element
    var b = 3; // 4 element
    var c = 5; // 6 element
    var d = 6; // 7 element
    var e = 9; // 10 element
    var f = 10; // 11 element
    var g = 1; // 2 element
    var h = 7; // 8 element
    var i = 8;; // 9 element
    var j = 2; // 3 element
    var k = 4; // 5 element

for (item = 0; item < 100; item++) {
      $('.grid').find("div.grid-item:eq(" + a + ")").addClass('grid-item--width2');
      $('.grid').find("div.grid-item:eq(" + b + ")").addClass('grid-item--width2');
      $('.grid').find("div.grid-item:eq(" + c + ")").addClass('grid-item--width2');
      $('.grid').find("div.grid-item:eq(" + d + ")").addClass('grid-item--width2');
      $('.grid').find("div.grid-item:eq(" + e + ")").addClass('grid-item--width2');
      $('.grid').find("div.grid-item:eq(" + f + ")").addClass('grid-item--width2');
      $('.grid').find("div.grid-item:eq(" + g + ")").addClass('grid-item--height2');
      $('.grid').find("div.grid-item:eq(" + h + ")").addClass('grid-item--height2');
      $('.grid').find("div.grid-item:eq(" + i + ")").addClass('grid-item--height2');
      $('.grid').find("div.grid-item:eq(" + j + ") p.card-text").hide();
      $('.grid').find("div.grid-item:eq(" + k + ") p.card-text").hide();
      a += 11;
      b += 11;
      c += 11;
      d += 11;
      e += 11;
      f += 11;
      g += 11;
      h += 11;
      i += 11;
      j += 11;
    };
  });
```

Classes are added before calling the masonry script.
The effect has been achieved.